# Automatically popup software keyboard when the app starts

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard

I have an editText on the main page. I want the keyboard to open automatically when the app starts and to be focused on that editText. I tried many "solutions" I found on the Internet but nothing helped me. 
The keyboard still doesn't appear automatically.
By the way, my editText has the following properties:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

So how do I make the keyboard appear automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do two things (I have just tested this and it works just fine):

**1:** request focus for the field. 
    From the activity java file you can do

```
   mTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);
   mTextView.requestFocus();
```

From the XML file you can rewrite your element as follows:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/textView">
    <requestFocus/>
</EditText>
```

**2:** Force the keyboard when showing the activity: in the `onCreate` method just write this line:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This thing really worked for me. 
The app continued crashing because of requesting focus in the activity. I simply removed that line. Now the keyboard pops up and it's focused on the EditText element.

Comment: I`m glad it helped :) You can mark the responce so that others can see it is the working approach.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible`" to your `activity` tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<activity 
    android:name=".TestActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />
```

Also use `requestFocus` tag in `EditText`.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: I still don't understand the reason why but this didn't help either.. I did everything exactly as you had written.

Answer (score 0):

Call myeditText.requestFocus() after you initialize your layout on your activity's onCreate() method.

Comment: remove focusableInTouchMode, enabled and focusable properties from your xml layout. Run your app again and if it crashes comment here and update your question with the error log

Comment: Yes, I tried it and again it has crashed. Sorry for such a silly question, but how do I get the error log?
BTW, I run the app on my smartphone. It crashes on the other one too.

Comment: I solved the problem by trying Krasimir's advice. Requesting focus  from activity caused the crash but I still don't understand how. I turned it off

Comment: I guess requesting focus from inside the activity would be a better aproach. Can you post your activity's code? Maybe we can fix it